# Using System.Speech.Recognition opens Windows Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

I tried implementing some simple speech recognition WinForms program in C# like the one described here in Michael Levy answer:

[good Speech recognition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467827/good-speech-recognition-api/5473407)

The problem i have is that any time i run the program Windows Speech Recognition opens and is also doing stuff based on what i am saying. Also when the program starts i have to say "start listening" for speech recognition to work.

[image]

My question is: How can i use speech recognition without having Windows Speech Recognition also act on what i am saying? I don't need Windows Speech Recognition UI to open at all and i need to be able to use recognition without having to say "start listening" before.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you are using an inproc recognizer for your application only. You do this by instantiating a SpeechRecognitionEngine() in your application. See [SpeechRecognitionEngine Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). I suspect you are instantiating a shared recognizer - [SpeechRecognizer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: that was the bug, had it figured later :) i combined code from many sources and i forgot to change that part