# Is there a way to make the Microsoft Speech SDK pay attention to only the commands I am programmatically looking for?

Tags: windows-7, speech-recognition, sapi

In Windows XP, the speech SDK works well with our application because it is not trying to do what it is in Windows 7. In Windows 7 the speech SDK attempts to interpret every command spoken by the user and control the entire operating system.

We would prefer to focus only on the dozen or so commands that our app is programmed to recognize.

Is there a way to focus only on these commands by turning off the other features?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a shared or an in-proc recognizer? It sounds like you need an in-proc recognizer dedicated to your application. See [Using System.Speech.Recognition opens Windows Speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6633521/90236) or [SAPI and Windows 7 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213035/sapi-and-windows-7-problem) which may help point to other info.

From [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2977338/90236)

> Desktop recognizers are designed to run inproc or shared. Shared
>   recognizers are useful on the desktop where voice commands are used to
>   control any open applications. Server recognizers can only run inproc.
>   Inproc recognizers are used when a single application uses the
>   recognizer or when wav files or audio streams need to be recognized
>   (shared recognizers can’t process audio files, just audio from input
>   devices).