# C# SpeechRecognizer vs SpeechRecognitionEngine

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Few questions,

1. What is the difference between the **SpeechRecognizer** and the
       **SpeechRecognitionEngine** classes? why use one over the other for
       speech recognition?
2. Is the speech recognition widget that I see in Windows 10 when I
   start my program has to be shown?
3. I loaded the **SpeechRecognizer** object with simple grammar such as
   "a", "b", "a r". it recognizes it perfectly but the time it
       takes is not ideal for my program, I would like it to be faster, any
       way to do that?

Comment: Have you read documentations of those classes especially remarks sections? There is information to answer your 1. question. For 2. try and you will see. 3. Buy a better pc?

Comment: 1. I will, thanks. 2. What do you mean try and see? the widget opens everytime I start my program 3. I have a macbookpro i5, I don't think that's the problem

Comment: 2. I don't understand what do you mean by saying is it has to be shown if it is shown when you start. Maybe you want to know can you control or switch it off? 3. Then what is slow and fast in thins case?

Comment: 2. I'm talking about this widget: https://imgur.com/a/3IR2QqS , is there a way Windows can do the speech recognition in the background and not show it to me? 3. How exactly do I measure? I think it's taking approx 0.1 seconds to recoginze and I want it to take less

Comment: 2. I guess you need to use SpeechRecognizerEngine to be able to control this. 3. `I want` is not a measurement unit, you need to do speed comparison. Maybe 0.1s for your grammar is blazing fast. Also it might depend on million reasons. Do you run it in debug mode or is it release build? Have you compared speed with other grammars and applications?

Comment: In the future, please only ask [one question per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  It makes things easier on everybody.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been answered in the past. See [Using System.Speech.Recognition opens Windows Speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6633521/90236), does this help?

In general, you can use System.Speech as inproc or shared. When shared, you see a recognizer "widget" on the screen. If you use an inproc recognizer, you control the recognizer and windows does not add a UI. See [good Speech recognition API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5467827/90236) for some more background.